# Collect terms in inverse powers of three variables

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, gathering

I have the following expression

[image]

```
-(((-(L/r1) + L/r2)^2*(L/r1 - L/r3)^2*(-(L/r2) + L/r3)^2)/(1 + 1/r1 + 1/r2 + 1/r3)^2) + (1 + L^2/r1 + ((-(L/r1) + L/r2)*(L/r1 - L/r3))/(1 + 1/r1 + 1/r2 + 1/r3))*
   (1 + L^2/r2 + ((-(L/r1) + L/r2)*(-(L/r2) + L/r3))/(1 + 1/r1 + 1/r2 + 1/r3))*(1 + 1/r1 + 1/r2 + 1/r3)*(1 + ((L/r1 - L/r3)*(-(L/r2) + L/r3))/(1 + 1/r1 + 1/r2 + 1/r3) + 
    L^2/r3)
```

Which I want to rewrite by collecting according to the inverse powers of `r1`, `r2` and `r3`. That is, I want to get

[image]

```
1 + (1 + L^2)/r1 + (1 + L^2)/r2 + (1 + L^2)/r3 + (3*L^2 + L^4)/(r1*r2) + (3*L^2 + L^4)/(r1*r3) + (3*L^2 + L^4)/(r2*r3) + (9*L^4 + L^6)/(r1*r2*r3) - 
   L^6/(r1^2*r2^2) - L^6/(r1^2*r3^2) - L^6/(r2^2*r3^2) + (2*L^6)/(r1*r2*r3^2) + (2*L^6)/(r1*r2^2*r3) + (2*L^6)/(r1^2*r2*r3)
```

I have done this by hand, but for more complciated expressions I want to use Mathematica. I tried `Collect[expression,{r1,r2,r3},Simplify]` but it did nothing for me. Also, I do not want to collect in powers of `L`.

Comment: You can get the coefficients of 1/r1,1/r2,1/r3 using: `CoefficientList[expression, {1/r1, 1/r2, 1/r3}]` Look it up in the help, for the output format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Total @ Factor @ MonomialList[Simplify @ expr, 1/{r1, r2, r3}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

To have the terms in a specific order, sort the monomials as you like and wrap the resulting list with `Apply[Defer @* Plus]`:

```
Apply[Defer @* Plus] @ 
  SortBy[Through @ {Total, Sort} @ Exponent[#, 1/{r1, r2, r3}] &] @
    Factor @ MonomialList[Simplify @ expr, 1/{r1, r2, r3}]
```

[image]

Using an alternative ordering of terms:

```
Apply[Defer @* Plus] @ Factor @ 
   MonomialList[Simplify @ expr, 1/{r1, r2, r3}, "NegativeDegreeReverseLexicographic"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pretty manual approach:

```
Total[
  Simplify@*Total /@
    GatherBy[
      List @@ Expand[FullSimplify@expr],
      Denominator
    ]
]
```

[image: collected]

Comment: This is nice. Do you think it is possible to get the output in the order I have specified above?

Comment: Maybe start with yours:
`Block[{sepTerms, invSepTerms}, 
  sepTerms = Total[Simplify @* Total /@ GatherBy[List @@ Expand[Simplify[Together[Qf[x, y, z] /. {1/Sqrt[(x - x1)^2 + y^2 + (z - z1)^2] -> 1/r1, 
             1/Sqrt[(x - x2)^2 + y^2 + (z - z2)^2] -> 1/r2, 1/Sqrt[(x - x3)^2 + y^2 + (z - z3)^2] -> 1/r3}]]], Denominator]]; 
   invSepTerms = CoefficientRules[test /. {r1 -> ir1^(-1), r2 -> ir2^(-1), r3 -> ir3^(-1)}, {ir1, ir2, ir3}]; invSepTerms = SortBy[invSepTerms, Total[#1[[1]]] & ]; 
   Apply[Times, ({r1, r2, r3}^(-#1) & ) /@ invSepTerms[[All,1]], {1}]*invSepTerms[[All,2]]]`

Comment: @ThunderBiggi `Plus` has the attribute `Orderless`, which means it sorts its arguments into a canonical order. Just try to keep `y + x` in the order `y + x`. You have to use something like `Hold[y + x]` or `Defer[y + x]` to keep the terms from being sorted.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I always struggle with all the Hold functions, as they either stay there and prevent me from doing anything, or just disappear and do nothing. Where am I supposed to use it here?

Comment: @ThunderBiggi I don't know because it depends. I was hoping you would just learn to live with the standard `Plus` ordering.  Here are a couple of Q&A related to fixing the order of `Plus`: [(15744)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15744), [(188576)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/188576).  If you need the order just for [tag:output-formatting], there is hope.  If you need to do further calculation with it, it is best to let `Plus` do its own thing, imo.